# Enviar dados para Base de dados

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um banco de dados com as seguintes chaves primárias e estrangeiras

```
tb_detalhe_trabalhador
    id
    tb_funcoes_id
    tb_trabalhador_id

tb_equipamentos
    id
    tb_trabalhador_id

tb_funcoes
    id

tb_trabalhador
    id
```

A minha última tabela a ser preenchida é `tb_equipamentos`. E me dá o erro:
`Column tb_trabalhador_id cannot be null.`

Tenho este campo:

```
$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO tb_equipamentos VALUES(0, NULL, '" . $MaquinaNumero1 . "',
```

Este `null` é o da `tb_trabalhador_id`

Comment: Apesar de várias edições, seu português ainda não está claro. Tente se expressar melhor, suas frases estão mal-formadas.

Comment: Poste seu código para ficar mais fácil de analisar o problema.

Comment: [Idente](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) o código de suas postagens por favor.

Answer (score 2):

Esse erro é uma mensagem do banco de dados dizendo que você está tentando fornecer um valor nulo a um campo que não pode ser nulo.

Pelo que entendi, você está tentando colocar um registro na tabela de equipamentos, e um campo desse registro é o ID do trabalhador. Verifique seu código para confirmar que você está preenchendo esse campo. Senão, edite sua pergunta e coloque o código próximo de erro para podermos te ajudar melhor.

Answer (score 0):

Você está tentando inserir **NULL** numa coluna que é `NOT NULL`, se você realmente quer atribuir **NULL** a essa coluna o jeito é trocar a coluna para permitir `NULL`.

```
ALTER TABLE equipamentos MODIFY tb_trabalhador_id INT NULL;
```